# error when trying to install glpi database on windows

Tags: php, xampp

this error appears when I install a new database in order to run glpi Uncaught Exception mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'glpi' in "C:\xampp\htdocs\glpi\install\install.php at line 418"

Comment: Use PHP 8.1 or report this incompatibility to them via their usual channel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.